# Conditional SetOverwrite

Tags: nsis

I am trying to dynamically set the `SetOverwrite` state for choosing between unconditionally replace some files or replace them only if my setup is providing some newer versions.

I have tried with logiclib

```
${if} $isReinstall = 1
    SetOverwrite on
    ${debug} "SetOverwrite on (overwrite)"
${else}
    SetOverwrite ifnewer
    ${debug} "SetOverwrite ifnewer"
${endif}
File "foo"
```

And with classic `IntCmp`

```
IntCmp $isReinstall 1 0 +3 +3
SetOverwrite on
goto +2
SetOverwrite ifnewer
File "foo"
```

But nothing seem to work: if my file `foo` is already present on disk, it is always skipped. My `$isReinstall` being `1` or not.

It seems that the last `SetOverwrite` statement in the stream of instructions (regardless of the logiclib macros) overloads the previous one.

If I add another `SetOverwrite on` just before the `File` directive, the file is correctly replaced.

Is my analysis correct? How could I decide at runtime if a file can or cannot be replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this code instead:

```
${If} $isReinstall = 1
  SetOverwrite on
  File "foo"
${Else}
  SetOverwrite ifnewer
  File "foo"
${EndIf}
```

The important point to note is that the File command appears within the If block and this needs to be done because the SetOverwrite command affects **every** line below it. See [this](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.2) piece of the NSIS documentation for a full explanation.

Comment: I was fearing this kind of explanation, while did not found it myself in the manual... In the real world case, I have many `File` statements to duplicate, in several sections. :( Thanks for pointing it to me.